# ML for data processing. What are the options?

Tags: machine-learning, data, data-cleaning, preprocessing, matrix

Currently I am working on improving a stage on a data processing pipeline. The source data has a large number of fields and is getting normalized into a simpler entity.
This entails that in many cases a destination field value may be copied from arbitrary input fields, according to the context.

My idea was to regress a binary output sources-destinations matrix that associates the possible source fields to the possible source destinations.

I was wondering: is this a problem that has been tackled before? Is there anything in scientific literature that is worth noting?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing could be modeled as [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph), one set of nodes connects to another set of nodes. Thus, it becomes a [bipartite graph matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Matching_in_bipartite_graphs) problem.

As the size of each graph grows it quickly becomes intractable, then [approximate nearest neighbor search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#Approximation_methods) might be useful.